# Função Hashlib em Python: TypeError: update() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, sha-256

Estou trabalhando em um script onde em um dos passos terei que utilizar a função `hashlib` para converter uma lista de strings em outra através da SHA256. Porém, estou tendo alguns problemas que ainda não consegui resolver.

Um deles é em relação ao código abaixo:

```
import hashlib
h = hashlib.sha256()
h.update("uma frase qualquer",encoding='utf-8')
print(h.hexdigest())
```

Inicialmente, aparecia o erro solicitando `encode`. Inclui o `encoding` no `update`. Porém, agora o erro que não consigo solucionar é:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-c4c9e8e0d84d> in <module>
      2 
      3 h = hashlib.sha256()
----> 4 h.update("uma frase qualquer",encoding='utf-8')
      5 print(h.hexdigest())

TypeError: update() takes no keyword arguments
```

Alguém sabe como solucionar esse pontos do "takes no keyword arguments"? E caso alguém teha algumas dicas que como converter listas de strings utilizando o `hashlib` (mais especificamente, SHA256), eu aceito também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se olhar a [documentação de `update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update), verá que ele só recebe **um** parâmetro, que é um [*bytes-like object*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) (mas como você está passando dois parâmetros, dá erro).

No caso, se você quer converter a string para bytes usando um encoding específico, basta usar o [método `encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), que retorna um objeto do tipo [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) (justamente o que `update` precisa):

```
import hashlib

h = hashlib.sha256()
h.update("uma frase qualquer".encode('utf-8'))
print(h.hexdigest()) # 2c7352c8cd51b0c07bc83c86e7c8e0fdace53e236fae91821ebfbfacc0a6592e
```

---

Quanto a "converter uma lista de strings", não está muito claro. Você tem uma lista de strings e para cada string você quer calcular o respectivo hash?

Se for isso, uma alternativa é criar uma função que calcula o hash de uma string, e em seguida usar [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) para aplicar esta função a cada elemento da lista:

```
import hashlib

# calcula o hash de uma string
def hash256(s):
    h = hashlib.sha256()
    h.update(s.encode('utf-8'))
    return h.hexdigest()

lista = [ 'abc', 'def', 'ghi' ]
# cria outra lista com os hashes de cada string da lista acima
hashes = list(map(hash256, lista))
print(hashes) # ['ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad', 'cb8379ac2098aa165029e3938a51da0bcecfc008fd6795f401178647f96c5b34', '50ae61e841fac4e8f9e40baf2ad36ec868922ea48368c18f9535e47db56dd7fb']
```

Assim, a lista `hashes` contém os hashes de cada string da lista original (no caso, os hashes das strings `'abc'`, `'def'` e `'ghi'`).